# Assemble altimeter for flights and send to ground station by RF

Tags: electronics, diy, altimeter

Hello everyone.
I'm looking for electronic help to build / assemble a bariometric altimeter that sends the altitude data at the moment to a ground station (arduino or others, smartphone, T 3000 etc ...) The first thing I need is to know how to feed the altimeter, this is the one I want to use ... [Pololu altimeter](https://www.pololu.com/product/2867)

The first thing I want to say is that I need to do it in light weight because it is to add to my bird that you can see in my profile picture, so the best is less than 10 grams including batteries if possible, I see other similar ones and yes we can . So please help and please don't do too much off topic.
The second thing you could answer me is that it will not have much range, to solve this I will have antennas on transmitter and receiver on the ground .
The third is my big quest, how I send the data via RF with a TX to the ground station? (that is, how I connect it via I2C) and if it is I2C who takes care of this.
Ok, simplly help me to make my own altimeter in realtime to my bird. Low weight, low price, high flights.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you mean here; are you just asking about how to transmit data by RF? That's more of an electronics.SE question IMO.